# Report in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex

I want to ask
If I want to add new column (time column) in report but I haven’t any permission to alter the creation table I need another method . Maybe we can separate the time from date time column or it’s impossible .

And I want to make the time count hourly not in second please .

This is the table which I have :

| datetime | clientchannel | servicename | service_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13_02_2022 9:35 | ***** | notification | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

Apply `TO_CHAR` function to `DATETIME` column with desired format mask, e.g.

```
select datetime,
       to_char(datetime, 'hh24:mi') only_time,      --> this
       clientchannel, ...
from your_table
```

---

Presuming, of course, that `DATETIME` column's datatype is `DATE`. If not (which would be a shame and an error), you'd use `SUBSTR`, e.g.

```
select substr(datetime, instr(datetime, ' ') + 1) only_time
from ...
```

---

**[EDIT]** As you commented that you decided to store date value as a string (bad choice, once again) and that code I posted *doesn't work*, here's a demo which shows that it does:

```
SQL> create table temp (datetime varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into temp values ('13_02_2022 9:35');

1 row created.

SQL> select substr(datetime, instr(datetime, ' ') + 1) only_time
  2  from temp;

ONLY_TIME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9:35

SQL>
```

Comment: Date time is varchar not date so I will use the second method

Comment: It doesn’t work both of them

Comment: It surely does; have a look at edited answer which now contains an example.

Comment: It doesn’t allowed to create  replace or insert ,

Comment: That cause I want to find another method

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. You don't have to CREATE TABLE nor INSERT INTO it as you already have that data in **your table** (I didn't, so I had to create one in order to be able to show you that code I wrote works).

Comment: It worked by using second method using substr ,it was my fault .thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

select substr(datetime, instr(datetime, ' ') + 1) only_time
2  from temp;

### ONLY_TIME

9:35